# How to connect to wireless network at boot automatically?

Tags: wireless, boot

Is there a package or a simple tutorial how to setup a *normal* 12.04 (not server) with wireless connection on by default?

Basically I'd like to be able to have my PC connected to the network *before* I login, so I can do *ssh* and run programs remotely even.
I've looked around but haven't spot any good tutorial yet. Could you point me to one?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I've done it easily, click on the network indicator, then head down to "Edit connections", then go to the wireless tab and find your network and hit edit:

[image]

Then I check "Available to all users", which makes the connection systemwide. I always have enabled this to make the system connect to the wireless while it's booting, but should work fine for your needs.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Cheers

Comment: I works brilliantly! Cheers! :-)